# Implementing a template Binary Search Tree with Add and Delete node functions in C++

Tags: c++, templates, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I created a bst class with functions, but now I want it to work with templates. Here is my code so far to add a node, which does not work.

```
 template <typename T>
void Tree<T>::addNode(Node<T>*& movingPtr, T newItem)
{
    if (movingPtr == NULL)
    {
        movingPtr = new Node;
        movingPtr -> data = newItem;
        movingPtr -> prev = NULL;
        movingPtr -> next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        if (movingPtr -> data > newItem)
            addNode(movingPtr -> prev, newItem);
        else
            addNode(movingPtr -> next, newItem);
    }
}
```

If anyone knows where I can find an implemented template class for this already, please do tell. What errors am I making? I know the templates basics, but there is little info on the more advanced template uses that clearly explains how to implement template classes and functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1)Node should be template

```
template <typename T>
struct Node
{
    T data;
    Node *prev;
    Node *next;
};
```

(2)class should be template class

```
template <typename T>
class Tree{
public:
    void addNode(Node<T>*& movingPtr, T newItem);
};
```

(3)Create Node with template type

```
movingPtr = new Node<T>;
```

You can try the whole test code below:

```
template <typename T>
struct Node
{
    T data;
    Node *prev;
    Node *next;
};

template <typename T>
class Tree{
public:
    void addNode(Node<T>*& movingPtr, T newItem);
};

template <typename T>
void Tree<T>::addNode(Node<T>*& movingPtr, T newItem)
{
    if (movingPtr == NULL)
    {
        movingPtr = new Node<T>;
        movingPtr->data = newItem;
        movingPtr->prev = NULL;
        movingPtr->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        if (movingPtr->data > newItem)
            addNode(movingPtr->prev, newItem);
        else
            addNode(movingPtr->next, newItem);
    }
}


int main()
{
    Node<int> *n1 = new Node<int>();
    n1->data = 2;

    Tree<int> t;
    t.addNode(n1, 1);
    t.addNode(n1, 3);

    return 0;
}
```